# Marketing Cloud with Adobe Analitycs identifier

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to know if anyone knows what should i used as the identifier between marketing cloud and adobe analytics, the subscriber key or the subscriber id?

Answer (score 1):

It depends - Both are unique and consistent. You provide no information on what you are using as subscriber key. It could be email address, phone number, anything.

However, since subscriber ID is an internal identifier provided by Marketing Cloud, the chances of you being able to match it with any records outside of SFMC are non-existing. I will hence recommend to use Subscriber Key, as long as it is not hold any personally identifiable information (e.g. email address). To be on an even safer side, you should consider using a hash, e.g. MD5 of your subscriber key.